# Dovetailing a vector

Tags: algorithm, matrix

Suppose you are given a vector v[1..d^2] with d^2 elements,

> v[1] v[2] v[3] v[4] v[5] ... v[d^2],

and we want to fill the *d* x *d* matrix M diagonally instead of row-by-row or column-by-column.

For instance, if d=4, the resulting matrix would be

> v[01] v[03] v[06] v[10]
>
> v[02] v[05] v[09] v[13]
>
> v[04] v[08] v[12] v[15]
>
> v[07] v[11] v[14] v[16]

This technique remembers **dovetailing**, but, in this case, we want to fill a squared matrix completely.

How can one design an algorithm where given vector *v* and dimension *d* it answers the above matrix?

Comment: Note that every iteration, the indices where you place the vector elements get swapped. Also, the highest dimension of your coordinates gets alternated with the one below such that they always add up to the same number: e.g.: for `v4 v5 v6`: `(3,1) (2,2) (1,3)`: hence all coordinates add up to 4 in this case.

Answer (score 1):

I had a look at this problem, and I think I've found a pattern that maps coordinates in the matrix to indices in the vector. Look at the differences between the indices used to fill the matrix in the 4x4 example:

```
 0 (+2)  2 (+3)  5 (+4)  9
(+1)    
 1 (+3)  4 (+4)  8 (+4) 12
(+2)
 3 (+4)  7 (+4) 11 (+3) 14
(+3)
 6 (+4) 10 (+3) 13 (+2) 15
```

The offsets at the beginning of the column increase in an arithmetic progression, and the offsets between elements can be seen as taken from a list: `offsets = [2, 3, 4, 4, 3, 2]` offset by the current row and column. i.e. to go from `(r,c)` to `(r,c+1)` you add `offset[r + c]`.

We can define this offset as a function:

```
inline int 
offset(int d, int i)
{
    return i+2 - std::max(0, 2*(i-d+2)-1);
}
```

It produces sequences like this:

```
d=4: 2, 3, 4, 4, 3, 2
d=5: 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 4, 3, 2
```

Now we can use this in a loop to find the indices to fill the matrix with:

```
for( int rOff = 0, r = 0
   ; r < d
   ; rOff += ++r
   )
    for( int i = rOff, c = 0
       ; c < d
       ; i += offset(d, r + c++)
       )
        matrix[r][c] = v[i];
```

It's quite a complicated loop, with increments inside of increments, but if you pore over it a bit, it will make sense:

- `rOff` is the offset at the beginning of each row, and is updated by the outer loop.
  At the beginning of each row, we add the new row number to `rOff`, so we get an
  arithmetic progression: `0, 1, 3, 6, 10...` for values in `rOff`.

  *Notice that I use `++r` when updating `rOff`, because I want to add the value of `r` **after** the increment, not before.*
- `i` is the index into `v` for the particular row and column, `(r,c)`, and it is controlled by the inner loop. We update it using the `offset(d, k)` method that we wrote before, by using the explanation above (that to go from the index for `(r,c)` to the index for `(r,c+1)`, we must add `offset(d, r + c)`

  *Notice, **this** time, I wanted the value **before** the increment, so I used `c++` to update `i`.*

If that's all a bit confusing, it's most likely because of the nested incrementing, so here it is, all unwrapped:

```
int rOff = 0;
for(int r = 0; r < d; ++r) {
    rOff += r; 
    int i = rOff;

    for(int c = 0; c < d; ++c) {
        matrix[r][c] = v[i];
        i += offset(d, r + c);
    }
}
```

As a sanity check, here are the outputs of the above loop, but with `matrix[r][c] = v[i]` replaced with `std::cout << i << ' ';` and an additional newline added at the end of each row:

### `d = 4`

```
0 2 5 9 
1 4 8 12 
3 7 11 14 
6 10 13 15
```

### `d = 5`

```
0 2 5 9 14 
1 4 8 13 18 
3 7 12 17 21 
6 11 16 20 23 
10 15 19 22 24
```

Comment: Very nice. I was thinking something similar, I found that `matrix[r][c] = (i + i^2 + 2ij + j(j+3))/2` for values above upper second/counter-diagonal, but I failed to find a closed form for the other part. This is a fine answer, I can't pick one answer in favour of another since there are more than one solution presented, but I'm voting it up.

Answer (score 1):

Things are rather simple if you just think in terms of two loops: one to traverse the upper anti-triangle and a second for the lower.  For the first, advance down the rows in an outer loop and the inner loop traverses up and right.  In the second, advance across the columns in an outer loop and again up and right in the inner.  Here's a complete C program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
  int d = 4, v[d * d], m[d][d], start, i, j, k, i0, j0;

  // Fill v with 1,2,...d^2
  for (int i = 0; i < d * d; i++) v[i] = i+1;

  // Start dovetail. 
  k = 0;
  for (i0 = 0; i0 < d; i0++)  // Down left column
    for (i = i0, j = 0; i >= 0; i--, j++)
      m[i][j] = v[k++];

  for (j0 = 1; j0 < d; j0++)  // Across bottom row
    for (i = d - 1, j = j0; j < d; i--, j++)
      m[i][j] = v[k++];
  // End dovetail.

  for (i = 0; i < d; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < d; j++) printf("%4d", m[i][j]);
    printf("\n");
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Things are rather simple if you just think in terms of two loops nests: one to traverse the upper anti-triangle and a second for the lower.  With this you need only simple counters and no `max` or `min` operations.

For the first, advance down the rows of the left column in an outer loop, with the inner traversing up and right.

In the second, advance across the columns of the bottom row in an outer loop and again up and right with the inner.  Here's a C program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
  int d = 4, v[d * d], m[d][d], start, i, j, k, i0, j0;

  // Fill v with 1,2,...d^2
  for (int i = 0; i < d * d; i++) v[i] = i+1;

  // Start dovetail. 
  k = 0;
  for (i0 = 0; i0 < d; i0++)  // Down left column
    for (i = i0, j = 0; i >= 0; i--, j++)
      m[i][j] = v[k++];

  for (j0 = 1; j0 < d; j0++)  // Across bottom row
    for (i = d - 1, j = j0; j < d; i--, j++)
      m[i][j] = v[k++];
  // End dovetail.

  // Print the result.
  for (i = 0; i < d; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < d; j++) printf("%4d", m[i][j]);
    printf("\n");
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
1   3   6  10
2   5   9  13
4   8  12  15
7  11  14  16
```

Comment: Both this and your last are Very nice and simple solutions, I liked it. I can't pick one answer in favour of another since there are more than one solution presented, but I'm voting it up.

Comment: Hmmm... Thanks. I don't know why SO created two different posts (a bug!).  I just edited the original a bit.